# Show the datepicker inside the overflow-hidden div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow

In my bootstrap table (I use `slimScrole`) there are date pickers (jquery datetimepicker plugin) in the data rows.
Because of the `jquery slimScrole` the `table` outer div is `overflow: hidden;`. So the data picker is going to inside the div and can't show as below screen shot. 
[image]

How could it show the datepicker that in inside the `overflow: hidden;` div ?
below is the code for the datpicker input. The inline CSS part is coming from the`slimslider` jquery plugin.

```
<div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: auto;">
<div class="table-responsive" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: auto;">
<table id="basic-datatables-schedules" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="p-relative">
<input id="start_2559" class="form-control required shiftfromdate" type="text" value="" onkeydown="return false;" style="width:10em;" name="start">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code here? One thing we could suggest is increase the `z-index` of your `datepicker` by seeing the above image..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao `z-index` is not working because of the `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: i have made a small fiddle trying to replicate the scenario, but it seems to be working fine https://jsfiddle.net/5yszqxjo/ .. If this is not what you are facing do update the fiddle with actual scenario !!

Comment: @luciferous thanks for this but I've tried. still issue is there

Comment: @Miuranga , if you could just set up a quick fiddle that replicates the scenario . it would be awesome. :)

Comment: @luciferous actually your fiddle is correct but you are use the wrong datepicker. Here I use not defauld jquery datepicker, its  jquery datetimepicker plugin. http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Remove Overflow:hidden style for table-responsive div

it will work